# Questions regarding pygame image.load function

Tags: python, pygame

Hello fellas average textbook noobie here, so I recently got done watching this sweet tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw and decided to head straight onto pygame :D

problem is as follows, I have a folder I wnna grab buncha images from and there's many (30-40) using the pygame.image.load function (need them as sprites for my game), they're in a different directory from my python file, for example my python game is in "C:\PythonProjects\Programs\Pygame2.py" and the images in "C:\Users\user\Documents\Generic game"

I tried googling around and apparently u gotta copy the whole directory path like this to load each? (pygame.image.load("C:/Users/user/Documents/Le game/BG.jpg")
and am wondering if there's a way to do this quicker say like I had a project with 100+ images...

Big apprecation for taking the time to help <3

Here's my code for reference (the structure is messy but I'll change stuff around once I figure out this problem):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption("Potato ultra")
BG = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/user/Documents/Generic game/BG.jpg")
walkRight = [#need to use pygame.image.load function for images here]
walkLeft = [#Same case]

SW = 500
x = 0
y = 480
width = 64
height = 64
vel = 20
isJump = False
JumpCount = 10

def redrawGameWindow():

    win.blit(BG, (0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 200, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()


run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < SW - width:
        x += vel
    if not isJump:
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 0:
            y -= vel
            if y < 0:
                y = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < SW - vel:
            y += vel
            if y > 436:
                y = 436
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if JumpCount >= -10:
            y -= (JumpCount * 4)
            if y < 0:
                y = 0
            JumpCount -= 2
        else:
            isJump = False
            JumpCount = 10

    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to start you could have a variable to make it look cleaner

```
path = "C:/Users/user/Documents/Generic game/"
bg = pygame.image.load(path + "BG.jpg")
```

For `walkRight` and `walkLeft`, i assume they are animations so you can do a for loop. where the names are img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg...

```
for i in range(num_of_imgs):
    Dir = path + "img" + str(i) + ".jpg"
    walkRight.append(pygame.image.load(Dir))
```

or in one line

```
walkRight = [pygame.image.load(path + "img" + str(i) + ".jpg") for i in range(num_of_img)]
```

another way is to use `os.listDir`

```
filename = os.listDir("C:/Users/user/Documents/Generic game/")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use glob before loading the image.

```
import glob
imageList=glob.glob("C:/Users/user/Documents/Generic game/*.jpg")
```

Now, you have a list of images to iterate over like below.

```
for each_image in imageList:
    BG = pygame.image.load(each_image)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a string called `directory` and join that to every image path you load:

```
directory = "C:/Users/user/Documents/Generic game/"
BG = pygame.image.load(directory+"BG.jpg")
```

If you're loading a lot of images, you could have a list of file names and loop through them to create a new list of images:

```
image_names = ["BG.jpg", "example.jpg", "example.jpg"]
images = []
for image in image_names:
    images.append(pygame.image.load(directory+image))
```